# Is it okay to use Rails 2.3 with Ruby 1.9?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-1.9, ruby-on-rails-2

Short and sweet,

Is it ok to use (current version) Ruby 1.9.1 with Rails 2.3.5?

Thanks for any additional info!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short and sweet: yes. [This link](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2009/11/30/ruby-on-rails-2-3-5-released) shows some small problems preventing full compatibility, but they are minor.

While [the download page](http://rubyonrails.org/download) recommends 1.8.7, we've been running 2.3.5 against 1.9.1 with no problems.

**Edit:** Here's the [really relevant link.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/2_3_release_notes.html#ruby-191-support)

Comment: Thanks! Extra link was helpful, too :)

Comment: Thanks @smotchkkiss, I included one more link for you which is actually the right one.